# Применение константы

Tags: java, android, android-intent

пытаюсь разобраться в коде. Но встретился метод к котором применяется константа `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE` и я не могу понять для чего она здесь и как её изменение повлияет на программу.

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: подскажите а то уже очень долго пытаюсь понять

Comment: я новичок в этом деле не судите строго)

Comment: Добавте Больше описания в вопрос.

Comment: public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue) { Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class); intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue); return intent; }

Comment: Не понимаю для чего используется эта константа , и как она влияет на программу

Comment: Можете собрать все ваши комментарии к вашему же вопросу и объединить все это в расширенный вопрос (его можно редактировать), с примером кода (его можно выделить).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Константа `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE` является ключом для передаваемых данных, по которому эти данные, в дальнейшем, могут быть получены в `CheatActivity`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    answerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
}
```

[подробнее](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent.html)